# Converting varchar type variable number without having decimal points

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I need to convert `varchar2` type value `100.0` into `100` (without decimal points) in Oracle SQL. Can you please help me?I used `regexp_substr`...but it fails in one situation given below.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(0.1,'(\d*)') FROM DUAL;---it results in Null but i want zero(0).
```

Note:- in Orcale sql developer

Comment: is not the first parameter of REGEXP_SUBSTR supposed to be a string? it seems you provided a float.

Comment: Try `SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR("0.1", '^\d+') FROM DUAL;` or use `CAST` to convert float to varchar.

Comment: If that varchar2 doesn't contain other text besides a decimal number then you could do it without a regex.  `TO_CHAR(FLOOR(TO_NUMBER("0.1")))`

Comment: Thanks LukStorms.

Comment: @LukStorms sounds like an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to display number in format You wish it to be displayed, so You should use formating functions. No need for rounding here in my opinion - query below should give You what You want.

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER('100.1'),'FM9999') as res
FROM 
    dual
;
```

More on number formats can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34577).

Answer (score 0):

**Try to this....**

```
SELECT TRUNC(TO_NUMBER(100.5)) FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Although this code might (or might not) solve the problem, a good answer should always explain what the code does and how it helps.